# Unable to push in Git. Why?

Tags: git

Here is my current branch setup in Git

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F (remotes/origin/master) -> G -> H -> I (personal/aconard/FXPricing)

-> G -> H -> I (remotes/origin/FXPricing)
```

Both commits B and G derive from commit A. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is rebase my entire branch on top of the master branch as shown above.

I am getting the following errors when I attempt to push in Git (using the --force option):

```
$ git push --force origin personal/aconard/FXPricing
Counting objects: 629, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (343/343), done.
Writing objects: 100% (580/580), 762.64 KiB, done.
Total 580 (delta 347), reused 416 (delta 230)
remote: + refs/heads/personal/aconard/FXPricing tmlight aconrad DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/personal/aconard/FXPricing
To ssh://git@dtml-orl-bld1/tmlight
 ! [remote rejected] personal/aconard/FXPricing -> personal/aconard/FXPricing (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@dtml-orl-bld1/tmlight'
```

What am I doing wrong? One thing I noticed is that my username has a typo on this error line:

```
remote: + refs/heads/personal/aconard/FXPricing tmlight aconrad DENIED by fallthru
```

It should be "aconard" not "aconrad". Could this have something to do with why I can't push my changes?

Comment: If G makes the same code changes as G', but they have different meta-data, it is customary to refer to them with different names.  eg, G and G'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hook installed on the destination that is refusing your push. Is the destination a server you have control of? If so, what is in the `pre-receive` hook?

edit: A quick google search seems to imply that `DENIED by fallthru` comes from gitolite. Are you using a gitolite server?

Comment: I do not know. What I do know for sure is that I don't have access to the server. Should I be able to do what I'm trying to do above?