# git push origin DENIED by fallthru, hook declined: gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite, git-push

I am having a problem pushing with `git` using Gitolite.
When I try this:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/deployment
```

I get this error:

```
remote: D NAME/install.py repos michael DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/deployment
To gitolite@admin:repos
 ! [remote rejected] deployment (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitolite@admin:repos'
```

I have given the group **`deploy`** [of which the user **`michael`** is a member of] permission to delete branches in the Gitolite config:

```
@deply  =   michael

repo  repos

        RWD    =   @deply
```

I have seen this post: "[Unable to push in Git. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121005/unable-to-push-in-git-why)"

But I am not using any hooks that I am aware of and cannot find anything thing else that might relate.

Is there something im missing perhaps?
Has anybody come across this?

Comment: What gitolite version are you using?

Comment: i installed this version of gitolite:
1.5.4-2

Comment: I hope not ;) This should be a V2 or V3: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207919/issue-in-gitolite#comment13110183_10207919 to determine the Gitolite version.

Comment: ssh to the server gives me: 
hello michael, the gitolite version here is 1.5.4-2~bpo50+1 (Debian)

Comment: That seems to be an *incredibly* **old** version of Gitolite (July 23, 2010), and maybe related to https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/09195afd443e3fb92b5c8f62fb3971a176d09c31/src/gitolite.pm#L51 in term of error message.

Comment: thanks. ive had a look at the error message and it doesnt help my understanding of the problem unfortunately... 
id like to upgrade gitolite but im using **ubuntu10.04LTS** and a higher version of gitolite isnt available in the repository for that version...

Comment: Consider installing it manually...

Answer (score 19):

You need `RW+` permission for ref changes/deletion

> RW+, for "push -f" or ref deletion allowed (i.e., destroy information)

Also, if you're using V2 this may apply:

> RWD and RW+D, for ref deletion. Once you use this in a repo, a normal RW+ can no longer delete a ref; it can only rewind

Sources:

http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/conf.html

http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html

Comment: both above source links gets navigated to page not found

Answer (score -6):

This worked for me, when nothing else would:

```
cd ~gitlab/gitlab
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_keys RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:gitolite:update_repos RAILS_ENV=production
```