# Why can't I push new tags to server

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I just tagged a release and I am trying to push the tag to the server but I am getting the following error

```
$ git push --tags 
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 190 bytes, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: FATAL: W refs/tags/v3.1.01 project xxsmith DENIED by refs/.*
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/tags/v3.1.01
To ssh://git@server/project
 ! [remote rejected] v3.1.01 -> v3.1.01 (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@server/project'
```

Why is this? I have full rights to the account.

I am using gitolite.. can it be something with the following setup

```
repo project
    RW+ master  = @releasers    # allow @releasers access to release branch
    - master   = @developers    # deny @developers access to release branch
    RW develop = @developers    # allow @developers access to development branch
    RW+ develop = @releasers    # allow @developers access to development branch
    - = @all                    # deny all other permissions
```

Comment: The server has a git hook which is rejecting your tags. [More on hooks.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: it cant.. I setup the server... lol. with gitolite..

Comment: Is this gitolite with GitLab?

Comment: I dont think gitlab how can I check

Comment: What’s in your `gitolite.conf`?

Comment: Oh just gitolite if you installed it. [There's another StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429201/git-push-origin-denied-by-fallthru-hook-declined-gitolite) that seems to hint it's an issue with old versions of Gitolite that can be fixed by updating Gitolite and/or fixing permissions.

Comment: the above is my conf.. can you show me the fix

Comment: Ok, with that conf I'm guessing you're expecting that you're in the `@releasers` group?

Comment: yes. I am in the releasers group

Answer (score 5):

## Gitolite Issues

There's an [older StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429201/git-push-origin-denied-by-fallthru-hook-declined-gitolite) that addresses the same issue. In summary:

- You need `RW+` permission for ref changes/deletion (change your [gitolite configuration](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/conf.html)). Based on your gitolite configuration, you likely want:

  `RW+ refs/tags = @releasers # Allow @releasers to push tags`

  What was preventing this previously was the denying of all other permissions.

  `- = @all                    # deny all other permissions`
- Updating Gitolite may help (making sure to update keys & repos)

## Server Side Hooks

From this, it looks like a [server side hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is possibly preventing you from pushing the tag(s).

On the remote end, look in the hooks folder inside the git folder. The pre-receive or update hooks might be the problem hooks.

## Use the force

On the other hand, you could also try to force push the tags `git push -f --tags`.

Comment: I dont see how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.. I had to add the following to the conf

```
 RW refs/tags = @releasers
```